# Prove that sequence {$\sin(n!x\pi)$} has a limit where $x\in \mathbb Q$ and $n\in \mathbb N$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

This is a question from Goldberg Method of Analysis but I am finding a contradiction to the statement. Let $L$ be the limit of the sequence. Then $L=\sin(q)$ where $q\in \mathbb Q$. Then $-e<\sin(n!x\pi)-\sin(q)<e$ where $ e > 0$.  And it follows that  $-e<2\sin(\frac{(n!x\pi)-q)}{2})\cos(\frac{(n!x\pi)+q)} {2})<e$. As both sin and cos is there in the equation their maximum value can be 1 hence the equations maximum value is 2 we can chose e to be 1. This is a contradiction.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If $q=\frac a b$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers and $b>0$ then $\sin (n! q\pi)=0$ whenever $n >b$, so the sequence converges to $0$. You are making things too complicated.

Comment: The equation's (2 sin cos) maximum value is 2, but it is going to be 0 for large enough n, as the previous comment says. The definition of limit looks at "large enough n".

Comment: Since when 2<3 is a contradiction?

Comment: Why should $L$ equal $\sin q$ for a rational $q$? If the limit exists, it's certainly of the form $\sin r$, because it must lie in $[-1,1]$, but you can't say more. Anyway, this is not so important: the main problem with your argument is that you find no contradiction at all: the maximum of the expression $2\sin\alpha\cos\beta$ is indeed $2$, but there's no reason for *your* expression to reach the maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find a contradiction, because, for instance, the statement is true for $x=0$. Assuming your argument is sound, you'd find a contradiction also in this case, which is impossible.

It is true that the maximum of $2\sin\alpha\cos\beta$ is $2$, when *arbitrary* $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are allowed, but in your expression
$$
2\sin\frac{(n!x\pi)-q}{2}\cos\frac{(n!x\pi)+q}{2}
$$
the arguments to sine and cosine are linked by the relations $\alpha+\beta=n!x\pi$ and $\beta-\alpha=q$, so there is no reason for the expression to reach the maximum.

By the way, $q$ need not be rational: it's true that if the limit exists it must lie in $[-1,1]$, so it is the sine of some real number, but *a priori* there's no reason it should be rational.

The argument is much easier: if $x=a/b$, with $b>0$, then $n!/b$ is integer as soon as $n>b$, so
$$
n!x\pi=\frac{n!}{b} a\pi
$$
is an integer multiple of $\pi$. Therefore the sequence is eventually the constant $0$.